# Which is faster, reverse lookups in filter or forward lookups to pks in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django model structure that looks like this:

```
# Pre-defined User model

class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    relevant_users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    related_A = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

And given a `User`, I want to quickly generate a queryset of all A's attached to B's where the user is in the `relevant_users` many-to-many. I expect lots of A's, but only one or two B's per A, with indexing on pk's only.

I have two methods for generating this queryset, and both work:

**Method 1:**
Filter A objects with reverse lookup.

```
queryset = A.objects.filter(B__relevant_users__exact=user)
```

**Method 2:**
Get a list of the A pks with forward lookup, then find those pks in the A table. (select_related is used, but omitted here for clarity)

```
a_pks = [b.related_A.pk for b in user.b_set.all()]
queryset = A.objects.filter(pk__in=a_pks)
```

Are these equivalent? Do they have the same time complexity, for large numbers of A?

edit: Looks like method 2 is faster in certain cases:

for sparsely populated `relevant_users` (mostly blank):

A: 10,000
m1: 0.0014s
m2: 0.0024s

A: 100,000
m1: 0.0016s 
m2: 0.0028s

For heavily populated `relevant_users` (all B's have at least one user):

A: 10,000
m1: 0.040s
m2: 0.019s

A: 20,000
m1: 0.066s
m2: 0.031s

Comment: that is interesting find.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old post now, but I just wanted to say thanks for producing some numbers on this, very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Method 2 take two round-trips to the database so is naturally almost two times slower than method 1, which takes only one round-trip. Avoid making two queries when you can do just one, unless the one query requires overly complicated aggregation that can sometimes be performed faster on the client-side in python.

Comment: Method 1 is faster for small A because of the overhead you mention. However, it looks like for large numbers of A objects and heavily populated `related_A` fields, method 2 is faster by about 2x despite the two database hits.